# Git and TFS - copy Git project to TFS and later merge changes done in both places

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, github, tfs

I'm experienced with TFS but new to GIT. I wanna know if this is possible and where to start:

I want to have a copy from a GITHub project in my TFS (it's a Visual Studio C# project). Then, I want to create a new VS Solution that will contain the GitHub C# project and other C# projects, and I want to check it all in TFS.
This is because I want to have a reference to Github project in my new projects and being able to Debug and step in the Github project code, and also, cos I'm gonna need to do some changes to the Github project code.
Finally, if the team that maintains the GitHub project adds a new version, I want to download latest, and merge their changes, to the changes that I've done in my TFS version (I assume the merge will need to solve some manual conflicts).

Hope that makes sense.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to clarify:  when you say "check it into TFS", do you mean you want to have a copy of this git repository hosted in TFS (as a git repository), or you want to use TFVC?

Comment: I want TFVC. Problem is that github project is out of my control, so, I need a copy into my own TFS because I want to use it in my projects and I'll do some minor changes in that tfs copy fixing some bugs and adapting to my needs. However, at some point, the github project team will update a new version, and then, I'll need to "merge" this new version with my customized copy into TFS. I could do it manually: get latest from github into a temp folder, copy all the files to my TFS copy except the ones that I've edited, for my edited files, I compare the files and merge manually. many thanks

Comment: Why don't you just contribute your code to the GitHub project?

Comment: As @edwardthomson said, you could now have a git repository into tfs. That's the way to go! Forget about TFVC, you won't be able to sync the repositories! Don't try silly things when you are beginner... And contributing from a github account is even a better and easier solution. Using your own nuget server could also help to easily include your custom versions in your projects.

Comment: @MrHinsh not sure if my client allow me to contribute to the Github project (I'll try to contribute with some changes)

Comment: @Philippe ok, I can have a git repository into TFS, but what will happen if I added the github project in TFS to another VS solution that is also under TFS source control?